# Validating presence of has_many through attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am currently creating a document management system that puts documents, and their potentially many versions, into categories.

My problem right now is using 'validates' to validate the presence of a category. This method was fine when I allowed a single category using an attribute within my document, but now I have allowed multiple, using :through => categorisations.

My form to create a new document asks the user to fill in a form that asks for 'title', 'content' and 'categories'. Title and Content are both attributes of the Document, whereas Categories is not, as it is pulled from using has_many :categories, :through => categorisation

My document model

```
has_many :categorisations
has_many :categories, :through => :categorisations
validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 25}
validates :content, presence: true
```

My category model

```
has_many :categorisations
has_many :documents, :through => :categorisations
```

My categorisation model

```
belongs_to :document
belongs_to :category
```

My section of the form to create the categorisations looks as follows:

```
      - Category.all.in_groups_of(3,false) do |row_category_names|
    %tr
      - for categories in row_category_names
        %td
          = check_box_tag "categorisation[category_ids][]", categories.id
          %label= categories.title
```

The section of the create method that creates the Categorisations that match the document:

```
  for category in params[:categorisation][:category_ids]
    Categorisation.create(:document_id => @document.id, :category_id => category)
  end
```

Doc Versions 'show' looks as follows:

```
    - @doc_version.document.categories.each_with_index do |category, index|
      - if index == @doc_version.document.categories.size - 1
        = category.title
      - else
        = category.title + ", "
```

Everything works as intended when at least one category is selected.

I have tried using all variants of 'validates' and 'validates_presence_of' for :category, :categories, :categorisations, :category_id, etc and sure enough, they prevent the form from being submitted if a category is not selected, however, they also prevent the form from being submitted if a category has been selected. Therefore, it is not working as intended.

As the form is allowing no category to be selected, and still moving to the next stage without pulling up the validation error, I get this error in my 'create' method:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

  for category in params[:categorisation][:category_ids]
```

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. Let me know if there is any other information you need.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using HAML in my text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer from @GabrieleF I was able to develop the answer.

I created a validation, as advised:

```
validate :at_least_one_categorisation
```

and the method, as advised:

```
def at_least_one_categorisation

  if categorisations.size == 0
  errors.add :document, 'At least one cat. is required'
  end
end
```

I then needed to add

```
if(params.has_key?(:categorisation)
```

into the created method where the error was occuring, as follows:

```
if(params.has_key?(:categorisation))
  for category in params[:categorisation][:category_ids]
    @document.categorisations.build(:document_id => @document.id, :category_id => category)
  end
  @document.categorisations << Categorisation.where(:document_id => @document.id)
end
```

If there is no category selected, the above if becomes false, and there is no categorisation, so the validation displays the error before anything gets saved.

Thank you for the help, GabrieleF.
Now, I just need to develop this some more to remove problems with editing the categories within a document.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to document model a custom validation:

> validate :at_least_one_categorisation

and then add the method, maybe something like

> private
>
> def at_least_one_categorisation
>
> ```
> if categorisations.size == 0
>   errors.add :document, 'At least one cat. is required'
> end
> ```
>
> end

Comment: Unfortunately this presents the same error I had beforehand, where it would display the error regardless of if something was selected or not. I assume because this method is looking for categorisations with the same document_id as the document it is about to create, however, the categorisation isn't created until after the document is created using the form (and therefore size will always = 0? I think I require something that will check if `for category in params[:categorisation][:category_ids]` is size == 0?